# html5 to mobile appp : using phonegap CLI

Tags: html, cordova, cordova-cli

I need to convert my following HTML appp to Android, iphone & windows-8 app using phone gap Cli.

I have installed CLI interface of phonegap as per this link :--
http://phonegap.com/install/

Now do i need some SDK for Android or IOS or windows-8 ?

Or phonegap CLI do not need any supporting SDK to convert HTML apps to mobile apps ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"/>
  <title>My Mobile App</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="settings.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    test();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

settings.js file :---

```
function test()
{
   alert('clicked');
}
```

Comment: if you are using phonegap build(https://build.phonegap.com/) no need for SDK but you need developer key for IOS

Comment: link you suggested what will it do.. ? will it copy my app to remote cloud server & compile their & produce apps for me ... right ?

Comment: I am using http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: yes exactly..then you can compile the app in cloud ..

Comment: And where to put my HTML , javascript & css files .. ? do i have to put it manually on cloud server... ? or i have to create a project ... what exactly is the process ?

Comment: please read this http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/introduction_getting_started.md.html

Comment: I read this link .. but it does not say any thing which command to run to communicate with cloud server so that it can convert into mobile app .....my directory structure is inside directory Project i have css, javascript, html, images : project/css , project/html, project/js, project/images

Comment: it also says to pack your app in following format ..  W3C Widget Packaging specification.

Comment: what you want to do after creating phonegap project you need to copy the www folder and make it a zip file just upload your www zip here https://build.phonegap.com/apps

Comment: should i use the same process & phonegap CLI http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface  ... and  config.xml file is at the top level of your application index.html file ... right ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a phonegap project from cli then put your html in www folder and build it with phonegap cli.

like

phonegap build android

phonegap build ios

Comment: do i need ios & android SDK installed on my PC in this case .. ?

Comment: it is not required as you can directly test on device but if you install android or ios sdk then you can log errors from device. also if you are just starting than it will help you in testing on sdk.